# SSLClient not able to serve more than 3 requests/sec during jMeter Load Testing

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, web-services, sockets

I have a Spring-boot based REST API which in turn consumes another Secure SOAP Service . All works fine until I load test it with jmeter , Even a simple 5 Requests/Sec causes example errors like below .

```
example 1 : 
             Error :Socket closed
example 2 :
             java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input
```

Given that the line `sslContext = sslconfig.setupSSLContext();` would load the Truststore and Keystore successfully to setup the SSL Context , below is my SSLClinet.

```
public class SSLClient {
    
        static SSLClient _sslClient = null;
        int _responseCode = -1;     
        URL url_ = null;
        HttpsURLConnection connection_ = null;
        static SSLContext sslContext = null;
        
        private SSLClient(EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig,PropertyConfig propertyConfig) {
            SSLUtil sslconfig = new SSLUtil(environmentConfig,propertyConfig);
            sslContext = sslconfig.setupSSLContext();
        }
        
        public static SSLClient getSSLClient(EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig,PropertyConfig propertyConfig) {
            if (_sslClient == null) {
            _sslClient = new SSLClient(environmentConfig,propertyConfig);
            }
            return _sslClient;
        }
        
        private boolean setSSLConnection(URL url, String method, String msgtype) {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext
            .getSocketFactory());
            try {
                connection_ = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection_.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                if(method == "POST")
                    connection_.setRequestMethod(method);
                connection_.setDoOutput(true );
                connection_.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", msgtype /*"text/xml" */ );
                connection_.connect();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred while establishing connection to SSL server. Error :"+ e.getMessage());
                log.error(e);
                connection_.disconnect();
                connection_ = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        public void releaseConnection() {
            connection_.disconnect();
            connection_ = null;
        }
        
        /**
         * 
         * @param url
         * @param method
         * @param message
         * @param msgtype json or xml
         * @return
         */
        public String sendRequest(URL url, String method, String message, String msgtype) {
            String response = null;
            if (setSSLConnection(url,method,msgtype)) {
                try{
                    //Sending the request to Remote server
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection_.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write(message);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    _responseCode = connection_.getResponseCode();
                    log.info("Server Response Code :" + _responseCode);
                    // reading the response
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection_.getInputStream());
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                    char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
                    int num;
                    while ( -1 != (num = reader.read( cbuf )))
                    {
                        buf.append(cbuf, 0, num );
                    }
                    response = buf.toString();
                    reader.close();
                  }catch(Exception e){
                    response = "<EXCEPTION>Exception occurred while sending message</EXCEPTION>";
                    log.error("Exception occurred while sending Request. Error :"+ e.getMessage());
                    log.error(e);
                 }
            }
            releaseConnection();
            return response;
        }

}
```

I use the client in one of the service impl classes as below ( The code below is called for each request which comes in )

```
SSLClient sslClient = SSLClient.getSSLClient(environmentConfig,propertyConfig);
response = sslClient.sendRequest(url, "POST", message, msgtype);
```

As you see in SSLClinet , I'm creating a Singleton object for HttpsURLConnection
Is Opening and Closing the connection for every request creating the problem ?
Should i implement some better ways to effectively access a Secured SOAP Webservice ?